# How can I get property groups with options for specific categories?

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I have a data resolver for specific cms block. The configuration of the cms block stores the IDs of chosen property groups. It means that:

```
$config = $slot->getFieldConfig();

        if (! $selectedProperties = $config->get('selectedProperties')) {
            return null;
        }
var_dump($selectedProperties->getValue()); //This will return the ids of the property group chosen in the configuration of the block.
```

Now, How can I build the specific criteria to get property groups with options for specific categories?

I tried something like:

```
$criteria = ($selectedProperties->getValue()) ? new Criteria($selectedProperties->getValue()) : new Criteria();
        $criteria->addAssociation('options');
        $criteria->getAssociation('options.productProperties.categories')->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('id', '16561f02419949feb5ac61a4ee6c6211'));
        $criteria->getAssociation('options')->addSorting(new FieldSorting('name', FieldSorting::ASCENDING));
```

but this is not working.

I need this because I have a menu with a submenu showing after hover. E.g (In the menu we have item `Wine` and after hover we want to have the submenu with subcategories country - Germany, Usa, Swiss, type -pink, white, red  etc(property group and options).

Answer (score 0):

How did you add the input field to the cms element? Is it a simple input field?

I added a property group selection to an cms element by using the `sw-entity-multi-select` component. No resolver needed.

```
    <sw-entity-multi-select
        v-model="element.config.liability.value"
        entity-name="property_group"
        class="sw-cms-layout-assignment-modal__option-group-select"
        label="Verknüpfung Haftung"
        placeholder="Eigenschaft"
    />
```

A dump of element.translated.config.liability

```
array:2 [▼
  "value" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:15 [▼
      "id" => "0189f35fbd607269b3983057907183fe"
      "name" => "Haftung"
      "options" => []
      "apiAlias" => "property_group_foreign_keys_extension"
      "position" => 1
      "createdAt" => "2023-08-14T09:47:14.300+00:00"
      "updatedAt" => "2023-08-14T11:50:57.362+00:00"
      "filterable" => true
      "translated" => array:4 [▶]
      "description" => "Haftung"
      "displayType" => "text"
      "sortingType" => "alphanumeric"
      "customFields" => null
      "translations" => []
      "visibleOnProductDetailPage" => true
    ]
  ]
  "source" => "static"
]
```